# When will a cofibration be a principal cofibration?

Tags: homotopy-theory, cofibrations

Let X and Y be CW complexes. Then the inclusion $j:X\vee Y\to X\times Y$ is a cofibration with cofibre $X\wedge Y$. According to Hans J. Baues' book *Principal fibrations and cofibrations, obstructions and differences* Definition 1.2.1, a closed cofibration $X\subset Y$ is a principal cofibration if there is a map
$f: A\to X$ and a homotopy equivalence $C_f\simeq Y$ under $X$. Question:  when will $j$ be principal? If so, what is $A$ in this example?

Comment: It's true if both $X,Y$ are suspensions. Outside of a few special cases, I don't think there is much that can be said generally.